# How to set an item to be the first in a for loop in Liquid if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have a for loop in Liquid which loops through customer addresses. What I would like to do is make the address which has been set as the default (customer.default_address) as the first address to appear in the loop. I currently add a default tag to the default address but struggling to make it the first to appear.
I tried using 'sort' but with no luck.
My current code is below.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
{% assign sortedAddresses = customer.addresses | sort: 'customer.default_address' %}
{% for address in sortedAddresses %}
  <div class="address">
   {{ address | format_address }}
     {% if address == customer.default_address %}
       <div class="default">DEFAULT</div>
     {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have default_address as a property of customer and Im guessing customer.addresses is an array of strings.  If you were to make customer.addresses an array of objects instead... with string property for address and true/false property for default, then you could do something like:

```
{% assign default_address = customer.addresses | where: "default", true %}
{% assign address_array = default_address | concat: customer.addresses %}
{% assign customer.addresses = address_array | uniq %}
```